# Não localiza elemento com findElementById

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, excel-vba

Caros,

Estou tentando preencher dois campos de texto (login e senha) de uma determinada pagina. Utilizando o seguinte código. (Tanto por byID, bySelector, nenhum funciona)

```
driver.findElementByName("usuario").SendKeys MyLoggin
```

Ao depurar o código, quando chega nesta linha retorna o seguinte erro.

> Element not found. Method=name, value=usuario

Testei esse mesmo código na pagina do Google e consegui realizar. A pagina pode ter algum tipo de bloqueio?

Answer (score 1):

Caros,

Resolvido, identifiquei que a pagina possui diversos frames, e os input's estavam localizados dentro de um frame especifico. Então utilizei o seguinte código antes de executar o findElement.

```
driver.switchToFrame ("login")
driver.findElementByName("usuario").SendKeys MyLoggin
```